# What is the origin of the huge difference in the autoprotolysis constant of heavy water versus regular water?

Tags: acid-base, thermodynamics, water

Basically, the gist of this question is, why is the autoprotolysis constant of heavy water different from that of ordinary water?

The autoprotolysis constant of heavy water at $\pu{25 °C}$ is $\pu{1.35 * 10^{-15}}$, while at $\pu{30 °C}$ it is about $\pu{1.47 * 10^{-14}}$. From this, I calculated that the enthalpy change for the autoprotolysis of heavy water is about $\pu{360 kJ/mol}$, which is already a *huge* difference from regular water's autoprotolysis enthalpy of approximately $\pu{+56 kJ/mol}$. The difference in entropy is also huge as well: by using the formula $-RT \ln(K) = \Delta G$ and $\Delta G = \Delta H - T \Delta S$ I calculated that the autoprotolysis of heavy water has an entropy change of about $\pu{+920 J K-1 mol-1}$, which is a world of difference versus water's approximately $\pu{-81 J K-1 mol-1}$. Can someone tell me why this huge difference in values is occurring?

Also could someone point me to a database that would contain this kind of thermodynamic data / equilibrium data because my textbooks aren't going to cut some of the questions I have in terms of raw data crunching.

Comment: Because you made mistakes in calculations?

Comment: *How* did you calculate these enthalpies?

Comment: @Mithoron: Using Van t'Hoff I get $\Delta H^0=+358\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$ for heavy water. And this resource: http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/water_dissociation.html lists the value for light water as $+55.8\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$. So it appears OP's values are correct, at least for the enthalpies.

Comment: However for the $\Delta S$ values I get different results: $-283.5\ \mathrm{J/mol}$ and  $-267.8\ \mathrm{J/mol}$ for heavy and light water, respectively.

Comment: For both light water and heavy water, my results from G = H - TS confirms the values that I got. My textbook also accounts for the change in entropy for light water ($\Delta S = S_{products} - S_{reactants}$) using the thermodynamic data that I got from it, but it doesn't have enough data for heavy water. Can you tell me how you got your entropy value for heavy water?

Comment: As you stated correctly: $-RT\ln K=\Delta H-T\Delta S$, so $\Delta S=\frac{\Delta H+RT\ln K}{T}$. I used the previously calculated $\Delta H$ at $25\ \mathrm{Celsius}$ (and the stated $K$ values). I'll check again. Update: just verified the numbers for $\Delta S$ and I get the same as I reported before.

Comment: As regards the reason behind the different $K$ values, this is quite briefly explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_water#Effect_on_biological_systems. Quantum effects make the $\ce{OD}$ bond stronger than the $\ce{OH}$ bond.

Comment: How does the deltaH value compare with other substances?

Comment: @OP, please [edit] in *all* relevant data to reproduce the values, so that no-one has to read a lengthy comment discussion